# Show the Quantity field on the product page but hide it on the catalog page

Tags: commerce

I created an "ABC Book" product, whose URL is https://example.com/product/1. I added the *Quantity* field from *Administration > Commerce > Configuration > Order item types > Default > Manage form display > Add to cart*.

The field appears on the product details page (https://example.com/product/1).

I created a view to display all products on a page (https://example.com/shop). The field also appears on the view.

How can I hide the field on https://example.com/shop, but still show it on https://example.com/product/1?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [views documentation useful](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views)

If I understand your question correctly, you may either set, for you view:

1. a different display under the view setting *format, content* and then set up the right fields you want to show on the product display configuration
2. On the view settings, again under the *format* sections use the *fields* settings, and then directly select the fields you want do display in the view

Comment: There is no specific field for quantity.

I have created a view mode for products, let's say its name is "teaser". I am using this teaser mode to display in the view (shop). But there is no quantity field to control its visibility.